# Mysql three queries combined into one

Tags: php, mysql

I have three queries:

```
$data1 = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                        FROM 'table1' 
                       WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
                         AND 'post_title' LIKE '$letter%' 
                    ORDER BY 'post_title' ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 

while($info1 = mysql_fetch_array( $data1 )){ 
  $id = $info1['ID']; 
  $data2 = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                          FROM 'table2' 
                         WHERE post_id='$id' 
                           AND key = 'the_key'")  or die(mysql_error());  

   while($info2 = mysql_fetch_array( $data2 )){
     $key = $info2['value'];
   } 

   if ($key == 'something') {
     echo "..."; 
     $data3 = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                             FROM 'table3' WHERE postnumber='$id'")
                or die(mysql_error());
       while($info3 = mysql_fetch_array( $data3 )){
         echo $info3['counter'];
       }
       echo "...";
    }
 }
```

I would like to use one query as three takes sometime, the queries I have tried take even longer...

I have spent a long time trying to solve this; this is not a 'do it for me', but please help.

Comment: Is there any reason you avoid linebreaks in your code?

Comment: The code is *unreadable*.  Reformat it so it is legible.  Do not use <code> tags; indent by four (or more) spaces.  Break the material into lines (ideally so that you don't get the horizontal scroll bar at all, but break it into lines somehow).

Comment: Could you please just edit it so that it's readable? :)

Comment: I always does this, I can't seem to make stackoverflow show my script as it should be

Comment: sounds as a lot of garbage, please format your code.

Comment: @alfie: do not use tabs - that confuses things.  Do not use the <code> tags; that doesn't get stuff right.  Do use the '{}' button above the entry text box to indent your code by 4 spaces.

Comment: What's the point of the "while($info2 = mysql_fetch_array( data2 )){ $key = $info2['value']; }" part? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: if the returned value of your query is only 1, could work, but on this case I try to use a JOIN. If the value returned was 2 or more, then $key for example assumes the last value and probably will not work as you wish. I recommend you to use a INNER JOIN but to use JOIN I need to know more about your tables.. There are a commom field in the three tables? If yes you are able to try a JOIN. Otherwise need to re-think your model.. good luck

Comment: But why are you only using the _last_ rows value column from data2?

Comment: Solved my problem remouved the if and used unique query by id

Answer (score 1):

Join your three tables on id.

Yeah, I could show you examples, but, there are tons of SQL JOIN examples already written. If you've looked at one of those, and have a question, ask it. But on the chance you haven't looked, let me not take up my time re-writing what you can more quickly google. (I'm not trying to be a smart-ass, just trying to most efficiently use my time and yours.)

Should you use a left join? Or a equ-join? I don't know, I don't know your data. If you want to replicate the code you have now, you'd use a left join. An equ-join is however, probably want you actually want.

Comment: This my be one of my problems, I've tried quit a few queries but they all take more time.. Not sure if I sould use LEFT OUTER JOIN, INNER JOIN...

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that after iterating through the 2nd query you take the 'value' of the last row returned.

But you cant rely on the ordering of rows returned from a database - so your query is no-deterministic.